# Using arduino uno and an adafruit shield to control 3 dc motors and a linear stepper motor

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, adafruit, stepper-motor

Hello I am currently doing a project at my university which requires me to order and program 4 motors using an arduino. I will be using an arduino uno and an adafruit motor shield. 2 of the dc motors will have an encoder for better motor control. While connecting the linear and one of the dc motors shouldn't be difficult, I am wondering how can I connect the two motors with encoders. 
I was thinking to connect 1 dc motor and the stepper onto one shield and the encoder motors onto another since the shields can stack. Is this option possible or should I use some other method? I am fairly new to arduino and only had a little bit of experience with coding so any help and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: It looks like Adafruit motor shield can control 4 DC motors and 2 stepper motors. So one shield should be enough. https://www.adafruit.com/product/1438

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The adafruit motor shield has enough connections for either 4 dc motors or 2 stepper motors therefore the most I could connect would be 2 dc and 1 stepper. So at least 2 shields will be required. What I am unsure of is can I even connect encoded motors to the motor shield or will I need to order another board specifically to run them.

Comment: You are right, my bad. Looks like you will need two shields then. But you will need stackable header. The ones that come with the Adafruit Shield is not stackable. Something like this: https://www.amazon.com/Arduino-Stackable-Header-Kit-R3/dp/B00PCCWEJG/ref=dp_ob_title_ce